# Word 2010 VBA Checkboxes

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word, word-2010

Hopefully an easy one.
I've got a Word document littered with Checkboxes. Is there any way to access these checkboxes as a collection I can loop through and check/set properties such as ID and Value?

For reference, I've already tried the ActiveDocument.ContentControls collection; it's empty.
I've also tried ActiveDocument.Fields. This actually contains the same number of checkboxes as there are on the page, but I can't cast it to a Checkbox to access the properties I need.

One final question, is it possible to dynamically assign an event handler to the click?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What version of Word do you use? Also, are the Check-boxes "normal" ones or ActiveX objects?

Comment: Word 2010. I'm not sure, do you know of a way to quickly check?
If it helps, it's type is Microsoft Forms 2.0 CheckBox

Comment: Right click on an object and see if you have the entry "Format Control..." in the context menu. If yes, then is an ActiveX. If not is either a normal check-box, or a legacy one (BTW, how old is that document?). Suggestion: put the Word version in you post for everyone to see.

Comment: I have that option, so I guess it's an ActiveX checkbox. Will update now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collection of all ActiveX fields embedded in your document (let's say its name is `ThisDocument`) is the collection `ThisDocument.Fields`. The items of this collection are objects of class `Field`.

To query the value of the objects in this collection, you'd use something along the lines of:

```
ThisDocument.Fields.Item(1).OLEFormat.Object.Value
```

To add code to the event handlers, just right-click on the ActiveX control, and then select "View Code" from the context menu. You'll get the Click event handler:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
     ' empty if event handler not set, VBA code otherwise '
End Sub
```

To insert code *dynamically*, you need to manipulate the Code Module directly, and add the event handlers line by line. This might be tricky but, basically, you'd do something like:

```
ThisDocument _
   .VBProject _
   .VBComponents(ThisDocument.CodeName) _
   .CodeModule _
   .InsertLines(<<Line>>, <<String>>)
```

where `<<Line>>` is where you want to insert (number), and `<<String>>` is the text that you want to insert. Be careful not to insert in the middle of an existing `Sub`, `Function` or custom type definition (obviously).

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically set an onclick event handler for it though?

Comment: Funnily enough, as you posted that, I managed to find very similar code through repeated googling and head-desking. Granted, your code is more informative and a bit cleaner. Now to figure out how to do the dynamic code insertion just once. Just a quick question though, is this the only way to assign the On_Click handler for a checkbox?

Comment: @Ryuu No. As I said, there is also the *manual* way: you right-click on all the controls, and type/paste code. It's not as much fun as adding them programmatically, but you'll have less headaches for sure. :-)

Comment: Fair enough. Just wanted to be absolutely certain that there was nothing similar to the event handling present in .NET etc, whereby multiple events can be handled by one function. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Ryuu Of course you can have a `Sub` that deals with events from several objects. The thing is, you need to "assign" the `Sub` to objects, and the only way is to call that `Sub` in object's default handler (that you need to declare like in the answer, `<<Name>>_Click()`). Worse, you cannot pass parameters to the click event handler, so your general `Sub` would be oblivious of the object that actually called it - which makes it less useful.

Comment: That's what I figured. Was just hoping for the best. Thank you very much for your help. I think I have a solution, just need to finish writing it. Not going to be the nicest way of doing things, but by what you're saying, it appears to only way of doing it that remotely resembles something dynamic